# Keyboard events not reaching X server

Tags: x11, xorg, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm on Raspbian 10 (buster) with no GUI. Then I installed X server and did a `startx` but then pressing keys on the keyboard has no effect on the screen, as depicted in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLT5Y.jpg).

When I plug the keyboard the following is written to `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, which indicates that the keyboard is in fact recognized.

```
[  2121.984] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Keyboard System Control (/dev/input/event2)
[  2121.984] (**) Logitech USB Keyboard System Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  2121.984] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech USB Keyboard System Control'
[  2121.986] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event2 13:66 fd 26 paused 0
[  2121.986] (**) Logitech USB Keyboard System Control: always reports core events
[  2121.986] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[  2121.986] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  2121.995] (II) event2  - Logitech USB Keyboard System Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  2121.995] (II) event2  - Logitech USB Keyboard System Control: device is a keyboard
[  2121.995] (II) event2  - Logitech USB Keyboard System Control: device removed
[  2121.996] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.1/0003:046D:C31C.0008/input/input11/event2"
[  2121.996] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech USB Keyboard System Control" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[  2121.996] (**) Option "xkb_model" "logitech_base"
[  2121.996] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[  2121.996] (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
[  2121.996] (**) Option "xkb_options" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
[  2122.003] (II) event2  - Logitech USB Keyboard System Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  2122.003] (II) event2  - Logitech USB Keyboard System Control: device is a keyboard
[  2122.044] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Keyboard (/dev/input/event0)
[  2122.044] (**) Logitech USB Keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  2122.044] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech USB Keyboard'
[  2122.046] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event0 13:64 fd 30 paused 0
[  2122.046] (**) Logitech USB Keyboard: always reports core events
[  2122.046] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event0"
[  2122.046] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  2122.053] (II) event0  - Logitech USB Keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  2122.053] (II) event0  - Logitech USB Keyboard: device is a keyboard
[  2122.054] (II) event0  - Logitech USB Keyboard: device removed
[  2122.054] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:046D:C31C.0007/input/input9/event0"
[  2122.054] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech USB Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[  2122.054] (**) Option "xkb_model" "logitech_base"
[  2122.054] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[  2122.054] (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
[  2122.054] (**) Option "xkb_options" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
[  2122.062] (II) event0  - Logitech USB Keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  2122.062] (II) event0  - Logitech USB Keyboard: device is a keyboard
[  2122.065] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Keyboard Consumer Control (/dev/input/event1)
[  2122.065] (**) Logitech USB Keyboard Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[  2122.065] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech USB Keyboard Consumer Control'
[  2122.162] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event1 13:65 fd 31 paused 0
[  2122.162] (**) Logitech USB Keyboard Consumer Control: always reports core events
[  2122.162] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
[  2122.162] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[  2122.169] (II) event1  - Logitech USB Keyboard Consumer Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  2122.169] (II) event1  - Logitech USB Keyboard Consumer Control: device is a keyboard
[  2122.169] (II) event1  - Logitech USB Keyboard Consumer Control: device removed
[  2122.170] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.1/0003:046D:C31C.0008/input/input10/event1"
[  2122.170] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech USB Keyboard Consumer Control" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[  2122.170] (**) Option "xkb_model" "logitech_base"
[  2122.170] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[  2122.170] (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
[  2122.170] (**) Option "xkb_options" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
[  2122.177] (II) event1  - Logitech USB Keyboard Consumer Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  2122.178] (II) event1  - Logitech USB Keyboard Consumer Control: device is a keyboard
```

I also suspected that the keyboard was recognized because when the display slept and I pressed ESC, it woke up. Also Ctrl+Alt+ works (I can change tty's).

If I do a `xinit` instead, same thing happens.

I have the following related packages installed:

```
ii  x11-xserver-utils              7.7+8                               armhf        X server utilities
ii  xserver-common                 2:1.20.4-1+rpt1                     all          common files used by various X servers
ii  xserver-xorg                   1:7.7+19+b8                         armhf        X.Org X server
ii  xserver-xorg-core              2:1.20.4-1+rpt1                     armhf        Xorg X server - core server
ii  xserver-xorg-input-all         1:7.7+19+b8                         armhf        X.Org X server -- input driver metapackage
ii  xserver-xorg-input-libinput    0.28.2-2                            armhf        X.Org X server -- libinput input driver
ii  xserver-xorg-input-wacom       0.34.99.1-1+b6                      armhf        X.Org X server -- Wacom input driver
ii  xserver-xorg-legacy            2:1.20.4-1+rpt1                     armhf        setuid root Xorg server wrapper
ii  xserver-xorg-video-all         1:7.7+19+b8                         armhf        X.Org X server -- output driver metapackage
ii  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu      18.1.99+git20190207-1               armhf        X.Org X server -- AMDGPU display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-ati         1:19.0.1-1                          armhf        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI display driver wrapper
ii  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev       1:0.5.0-1+b2                        armhf        X.Org X server -- fbdev display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau     1:1.0.16-1                          armhf        X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-radeon      1:19.0.1-1                          armhf        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI Radeon display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-vesa        1:2.4.0-1+b1                        armhf        X.Org X server -- VESA display driver
```

The events are in fact generated, as I can see with `showkey`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the image an xterm inside the X server?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani yes, it's the new screen I get after running `startx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your keyboard works, but the X application might not have the focus. Try this. In ~/.xinitrc add a line (create the file if it is not there)

```
xterm &
```

That tells startx to run that command on start. Try to type there. If it does not work and you have a mouse, click on the xterm window and type again. I f you don't have a mouse, try doing Alt-tab and see if you can type then.

Comment: This results in the following error and then the command exits: https://pastebin.com/WfbG4fv6. I too believe that it's simply a "window focus" issue, however I don't have a mouse.

Comment: I just found a (forgotten) mouse, plugged it in and it worked, so it actually was a focus issue. However, how should I fix this once and for all, and not require a mouse?

Comment: You could start but accepting the answer ;). And then, probably you want to have some window/session manager. [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151847/how-to-change-the-window-manager-on-a-raspberry-pi) has more information on the possibilities.

Comment: Accepted and upvoted. Thanks!